# Getting error while creating ReactJs Hello world program

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react while I am running hello world in react its give me a error **Syntax Error: expected expression, got '<'**.

My code is .

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>,document.getElementById('root'));

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for support.

Comment: We need more info, how are you running this code?

Comment: I am running this code normally in browser

Comment: If you are not transpiling it, you can't use JSX syntax, you have to use `React.createElement`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use JSX in plain HTML/JavaScript (`<h1>Hello, world!</h1>`).

JSX is not supported by the browsers directly, it needs to be transpiled (converted) to JavaScript at build time by Babel.

Alternatively, you can use React without JSX, your code would be:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('h1', undefined, 'Hello, world!'), 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

As 3rd option, you may embed Babel in your HTML file, but this is something you should do just for learning purposes since is not performant enough for production apps:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel">
            ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>,document.getElementById('root'));

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```